# Java (HttpPost, HttpGet, HttpPut, HttpPatch) methods in C#

Tags: java, c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

Following is the code snippet in **JAVA**.
I want to do the similar thing in C#, Metro apps.

```
public static String callWebservice(String paramJson) throws Exception {

    ...
    ...

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    ...
    if (requestType.equals("POST")  ) {
        HttpPost httpPostReq = new HttpPost(url);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonParam.toString());
        se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
        httpPostReq.setEntity(se);
        httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpPostReq);
    } 

    else if (requestType.equals("GET") ) {
        HttpGet httpGetReq = new HttpGet(url);
        ...

    } 
    else if (requestType.equals("PUT")  ) {
        HttpPut httpPutReq = new HttpPut(url);
        ....

    } 
    else if (requestType.equals("PATCH")  ) {
        HttpPatch httpPatchReq = new HttpPatch(url);
        ...
    }

    responseText = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());

    return responseText;

}
```

I wonder if there are separate methods of Java: ("**HttpPost**", "**HttpGet**", "**HttpPut**", "**HttpPatch**" ) in C# also.

I tried to accomplish the task using HttpClient but I'm facing errors while adding headers "Accept", "Content-Type", "X-Security-AuthKey" and throws error like:

> Misued header ...

But somehow I managed to add header using "**TryAddWithoutValidation**".
In my C# code, I have the code snippet like following:

```
private async Task<string> CallHttpServiceHelper(string json)
    {
        try
        {
            ...
            HttpModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HttpModel>(json);

            try
            {
                JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
                jsonObject["userName"] = JsonValue.CreateStringValue(model.paramss.userName);
                jsonObject["password"] = JsonValue.CreateStringValue(model.paramss.password);
                jsonObject["domain"] = JsonValue.CreateStringValue(model.paramss.domain);
                jsonObject["accessKey"] = JsonValue.CreateStringValue(model.paramss.accessKey);
                inputParams = jsonObject.Stringify();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            url = model.url;
            requestType = model.requesttype;

            try
            {
                authenticationKey = model.authenticationKey;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            if (requestType == "POST")
            {
                uri = new Uri(url);
                data = new StringContent(inputParams, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                if (authenticationKey != null && authenticationKey != "")
                {
                    data.Headers.Add("X-Security-AuthKey", authenticationKey);
                }
                httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
                httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, data); 
                content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                httpClient.Dispose();

            }

            else if (requestType == "GET")
            {
                uri = new Uri(url);
                httpClient = new HttpClient();
                if (authenticationKey != null && authenticationKey != "")
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("X-Security-AuthKey", authenticationKey);
                }
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
                httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
                content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                httpClient.Dispose();                
            }

            else if (requestType == "PUT")
            {
                ...
            }

            else if (requestType == "PATCH")
            {
                ...
            }

            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "fail";
        }
    }
```

This code in C#, Windows RT Apps works fine for **POST** method. But I'm not getting the required response from webservice in **GET** method. In **GET** method I have to call WebService by passing three Headers only "Accept", "Content-Type", "X-Security-AuthKey".
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It really depends on the specifications of the service you're trying to call, but I think "X-Security-AuthKey" should be added as a classical header, not `Authorization`. Also, you're calling `httpClient.PostAsync` on all your code paths, even when it's supposed to be a GET request

Comment: Yes thanks! I noticed that. And updated that GetAsync in "GET" method. But still problem with the header "X-Security-AuthKey"  in the "GET" method.